# Authenticate to Microsoft Graph api using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

***Update** - Hacking away this afternoon and I discovered that I was trying to authenticate using [ADAL authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) when I should be using [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet). I changed my approach to use MSAL, and have been successful, but this question still stands for ADAL auth.

I have been having a difficult time being able to authenticate with the graph API using powershell. My end goal is to be able to query some of my OneNote pages, and I am able to use the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to authenticate using my personal Microsoft account.

I have been following [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulomarques/2016/03/21/working-with-azure-active-directory-graph-api-from-powershell/), and this [more recent](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudlojik/2017/09/05/using-powershell-to-connect-to-microsoft-graph-api/) one.

I registered my app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and I have a application ID which I have plugged into the PS script as the `$clientID` and when I run the script I get an error: `Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext] does not contain a method named 'AcquireToken'.`

Looking at the .net documentation for the [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext?view=azure-dotnet) class there is no method named `AcquireToken`, but there are a few similarly named ones, although I cannot figure out which one I need to use. Ideally I would like my script to prompt the user for their credentials similar to how the `AzureRM` module's `Login-AzureRmAccount` function does. If that is not possible than I could use guidance on how to rework the code below to use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenASync

```
function Get-AuthToken
{

     param
         (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         $TenantName
         )
     Import-Module Azure
     $clientId = "00d16af4-d0c7-460a-a9dc-fd350eb4b100" 
     $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
     $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
     $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName"
     $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
$Credential = Get-Credential
     $AADCredential = New-Object   "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList   $credential.UserName,$credential.Password
     $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId,$AADCredential)
     return $authResult

 }
 Get-AuthToken -TenantName "common"
```

Comment: Since you used MSAL to resolve your issue. What's the else question for this case? Also, you can write an answer with how to use MSAL to achieve your scenario.:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe for ADAL you would pass a value from `[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]` into the `AcquireTokenASync` method in addition to the clientID, my apps' redirect URI, and the resource id "https://graph.microsoft.com". This code prompts me for credentials, but because I am not using Azure AD I can't get pass that point.

```
function Get-AuthToken{
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $TenantName)

    $clientId = "00d16af4-d0c7-460a-a9dc-fd350eb4b100" 
    $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
    $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName"
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    $promptBehaviour = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Auto
    $authParam = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters" -ArgumentList $promptBehaviour
    $authenticationTask = $authContext.AcquireTokenASync($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId,$redirectUri,$authParam)
    $authenticationTask.Wait()
    $authenticationResult = $authenticationTask.Result
    return $authResult
}

Get-AuthToken -TenantName "common"
```

For MSAL I found the [MSAL.PS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/1.1.4.1) module's `Get-MSALToken` function which prompted me and returned a valid token that I could use.

```
Get-MSALToken -Scopes "Notes.Read" -ClientId "00d16af4-d0c7-460a-a9dc-fd350eb4b100" -RedirectUri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
```

Comment: MSAL.PowerShell has been delisted by the owner.  Microsoft is making quite a few changes to the MSAL/ADAL libraries as of Oct 2018, I would not recommend using this module.

Comment: @JamesBlake, I updated the answer to point to the new MSAL.PS module which I confirmed with the owner is the replacement module to use.

Comment: @BrandonMcClure is this PowerShell module still work with the new MS Graph ?